# Enviar dados de um método para o outro na mesma activity

Tags: java, android

Eu sei que para enviar dados de uma atividade para outra é o seguinte:

```
String value = filename;
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReceberNome.class);
intent.putExtra("nameFile", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

E para receber:

```
String value = null;
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null){
value = bundle.getString("namefile");
```

Acontece que eu **não** quero enviar dados de uma **atividade** para outra, e sim pegar **dados** depositados em um **método** e enviar para outro **método da mesma activity**.

```
private void PegarNome(){
//Aqui eu consigo um valor onde não posso chamar no outro método, que é o filename

String value = filename;
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReceberNome.class);
intent.putExtra("nameFile", value);
startActivity(intent);
}

private void ReceberNome(){
//Aqui quero receber o filename que é obtido somente no método PegarNome()
}
```

Pra enviar eu já tentei:

```
String value = filename;
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("nameFile", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

Mas não obtive o valor, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só você passar para uma variável privada na classe.

```
private String value;
private void PegarNome(){
//Aqui eu consigo um valor onde não posso chamar no outro método, que é o filename

value = filename;
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReceberNome.class);
intent.putExtra("nameFile", value);
startActivity(intent);
}

private void ReceberNome(){
//Aqui quero receber o filename que é obtido somente no método PegarNome()

 System.out.println("O nome do arquivo é: "+value);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado mano, mas e sobre o Intent? Nesse código ele continua enviando os dados para outra atividade. Como faz com essa parte: Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), ReceberNome.class);?

Comment: Se você está na mesma activity, você não precisa iniciar um intent, basta apenas chamar o método e recuperar o valor da variável.

Comment: Exatamente. Muito obrigado ;)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode passar como parâmetro no método também, exemplo:

```
meuMetodo("Leonardo", "28 anos", "masculino");
```

E pra receber:

```
public void meuMetodo(String nome, String idade, String sexo){
     //Aqui usa as variáveis que recebeu
}
```

Abraços.